# How to count repeated words from the list

Tags: tcl

I have a list of cells,

1. U1864
2. u_dhm_lut/U4
3. u_dhm_lut/lut_out_reg_2_
4. u_dhm_lut/lut_in_reg_2_

And I want to calculate how many times each name comes
Result will:

1. U1864 1
2. u_dhm_lut/lut_out_reg_2_ 18
3. u_dhm_lut/lut_in_reg_2_ 14
4. u_dhm_lut/U4 10

The code is like:

```
set cell_cnt [open "demo.txt" r]
set cell [read  $cell_cnt]
set b [open "number_of_cell.txt" w+]

proc countwords {cell_count} {
set unique_name [lsort -unique $cell_count]
foreach count $unique_name {
set cnt 0
foreach item $cell_count {
if {$item == $count} {
incr cnt
}
}
puts $b "$count :: $cnt"
}
}

countwords $cell
```

It says can't read "b":no such variable while executing 
    "puts $b "$count :: $cnt""
Why am i not able write a file inside proc?

Comment: That's *another* FAQ. The reason your code in the procedure can't use the variable "b" is that it is global. Use ::b or invoke the command "global b" (no quotes) before using the variable. Also, consider using a little more straightforward code for frequency counting (such as in my answer). Future you will thank you if you ever work with the same code again.

Answer (score 1):

Code inside a procedure scope can't use variables defined outside that scope, e.g. global variables. To be able to use global variables, you can import them into the procedure scope:

```
proc countwords cell_count {
    global b
```

or use a qualified name:

```
puts $::b ...
```

You can also bypass the issue by passing the file handle to the procedure:

```
proc countwords {b cell_count} {

... 

countwords $b $cell
```

or move the code for opening the file inside the procedure (not recommended: procedures should have one job only).

**Old answer, based on the question title**

This is one of the most frequently asked frequently asked questions. If you look a while back in the question list, you will find quite a few answers to this.

The solution is actually pretty easy, and the core of it is to use an array as a frequency table, with the words as keys and the frequencies as values. The `incr` command creates new entries (with a value of one) in the table as needed.

```
foreach word $words {
    incr count($word)
}
```

The result is similarly easy to check:

```
parray count
```

The result can of course also be used in a script in any way that an array can be used.

Documentation:
[array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[parray](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/library.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open file code i.e  "set b [open "number_of_cell.txt" w+]" inside the method. This should also solve your problem